# Replace all text between brackets Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have String

```
String test = "
    test_one {
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    }
    
    test_two {
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    }
    
    test_three {
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    }
"
```

I need replace whole text between brackets in 'test_two' or 'test_three' with another text ex "This is my text";

Expected output:

```
String test = "
        test_one {
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        }
        
        test_two {
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        }
        
        test_three {
        **This is my text**
        }
    "
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and try to solve the task on your own first. If you come across a specific problem while doing so, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a regex replacement with dot all mode enabled:

```java
String test = "test_one {\nLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\n}\ntest_two {\nLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\n}\n\ntest_three {\nLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\n}";
test = test.replaceAll("(?s)\\btest_three \\{.*?\\}", "test_three {\nThis is my text\n}");
System.out.println(test);
```

This prints:

```
test_one {
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
}
test_two {
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
}

test_three {
This is my text
}
```